# Why PlatformURLResourceConnection doesn't support outputstream?

Tags: eclipse, url, rcp

Do you known how to achieve that url.openConnection().getOutputStream() won't failed if the url is "**platform:/resource/**... path in eclipse' workspace"?

When I did a closer look to the class org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.**PlatformURLResourceConnection** I found that the class doesn't implement the method

public OutputStream **getOutputStream()** throws IOException

Is there any reason for it?

BTW: 
It works fine for input streams but for output I do not see any reason why not to have a such functionality there.

Best regards,
Andrej

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not used to interact with the workspace, since there's the `IResource`/`IFile` API.  You can open an enhancement request at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform&component=Resources

Comment: The only problem with IResource/IFile direct access is that you cannot provide some decoration for further processing of resource by custom URL handlers. Each user of IResource / IFile needs to be explicit and add all parameters to file instead of out of box approach wherer params are added by "framework" and the final client of the file is not aware about the hooks behind the scene. Anyway thank you for your answer.

Comment: Dear Paul, thank you for your link. I created the issue for it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413250